# What transformation corresponds to the z-relation?

Tags: set-theory

Forte's list of set classes includes some pairs that are "z-related" -- you can't get one from another through transposition and inversion, but they have the same interval vectors. Every interval vector is shared by at most two set classes.

Given a set class, such as 6-z3 (012356), is there a known transformation that produces its z-partner, in this case 6-z36 (012347)?

By "transformation" I mean a mathematical procedure to change from one PC set to the other. For example, multiplication by 11 (mod 12) transforms each PC set to its inverse -- which operation transforms each PC set to its z-partner?

In the specific case of 6-note sets we have the Hexachordal Theorem, so we can define the required transformation as taking the complement. I'm looking for a generalized transformation that works for any cardinality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem identified here is the subject of deep research in set theory, category theory, crystallography, and music theory — to name a few. There is no known generalized transformation that works across cardinalities.

Emmanuel Amiot's textbook *[Music Through Fourier Space](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-45581-5#about-this-book): Discrete Fourier Transform in Music Theory* (Springer, 2016) might be of interest. Also research articles by David Lewin, Allen Forte, Robert Morris, Emmanuel Amiot,  Joseph Straus, Ian Quinn, Franck Jedrzejewski, and Cliff Calendar, among others.

Comment: Is the fact that every interval vector is shared by at most two set classes specific to 12-tones, or would it also be true for scales with different numbers of (equal-tempered) notes?  I would strongly suspect there is provably no possible generalized transformation - I don't know what the precise mathematical statement might be, but maybe that finding the z-partner(s) is an NP-hard problem (if you consider arbitrary sized sets in scales with arbitrarily many equally-tempered notes).

Comment: Note - for contrast, that inverse is always multiplication by -1, no matter the number of notes in the scale.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I believe that in 16-TET there are Z-triplets and that there are other groupings that pop up as the number of tones increases, but I can't immediately find a reference.

Comment: Thank you -- that makes me feel better about not being able to figure it out on my own :-). I'll check out Amiot's book, it looks extremely interesting! I'd be interested to know about the links with crystallography (via group theory, I assume?) but can make another question for that if it's appropriate.

Comment: @helveticat In crystallography, it has to do with non-congruent structures that produce identical diffraction patterns, because they contain the same sets of distances between atoms. Search for "homometry".

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! Plenty to dig into there...